Outlook sign disappears when I add someone in TO/BCC/CC
I have an issue with Outlook about the Sign automatically put in the email body. When I add a recipient in the To:,CC:, or BCC: fields, the sign disappears and I have to enter CTRL+Z to restore it.
This started two months ago but I checked on both the Office portal and Outlook settings and there is not anything related to it.
Has anyone faced a similar issue and have been able to resolve it?
Thanks

What sign is disappearing?

If the signature get erased, you will need to validate no transport rule override your settings (aka; https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/security-and-compliance/mail-flow-rules/disclaimers-signatures-footers-or-headers). It's the only way it can be programmed, except possible Office/browser addon on the compouter. (Test online maybe from a personnal laptop at home to validate the addon part)
